# spawn urdf model in gazebo by C++

Tags: ros, gazebo, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I plan to spawn a robot urdf model in gazebo by C++. Can anyone kindly introduce me any tutorial or code template for doing this?

My finally objective is  to implement my algorithm to control this robot in C++.  Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171346/spawn-urdf-model-in-gazebo-by-c++/) by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/28557/how-can-i-use-the-c-program-to-add-delete-object-in-ros-gazebo/

Check out the above question and following answers.

Or you could always just fork and give a command using system or one of the exec* functions.

something like

```
pid_t child = fork()
if (child == 0){
  system("rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file <path to xml/urdf file> -urdf -model <model_name>");
}
```

As to how to control the robot. Just publish to the topics the robot is listening to.

I've been using ros hydro and indigo to simulate and control a Turtlebot 2.0.
What I do is launch the gazebo simulator and turtlebot urdf model using

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

and then run my own programs I created with roscpp that issues commands through the cmd_vel_mux topic
and listens to the various sensors.

---

Originally posted by [Charlie Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18937/charlie-murphy/) with karma: 76 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1